# replace variables in querystring for url path asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i know there's a way to do this, but i just can´t remember how it was, i did search in the other posts about this topic but is not just what i'm looking for:

i have this

http://www.example.com/detail.aspx?userid=gartest&tutorialid=1001

should be like

http://www.example.com/gartest/1001

plase help, thaks

Comment: Both are the same. What is it you're after?

Comment: Are you looking for url rewriting?

Comment: i'm looking for orientation, sorry, why you say both are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asp.net webforms you can create ASP.net mvc like route rules to do so.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx